# Jenkins build and deploy separately

Tags: maven, jenkins

I need help in configuring a jenkins job. I am able to deploy the code using mule mvn deploy command in a single job. Now i need to build the package and use the package to deploy it to multiple environments with out building it again. Can some one help me with that. I am able to package the code using mvn package. BUt when I want to deploy the build package I am using mvn deploy command and this is compiling and building the code. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would build the project and then deploy it to *one* Nexus/Artifactory. If you need it in different artifact repositories, you usually proxy the original repository in the other repository.

If you really need to deploy the same file to two Nexus/Artifactory, you can add additional deployments using the goals in the deploy plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Meier. I am able to deploy the build package to artifactory successfully. I want to use the deployed package from artifactory to be deployed to mule anypoint runtime with out building the package again. When i used the command "mvn deploy" it's building the package again and deploying to mule runtime. I don't want the source code to be build again. I need to use the already built in package from artifactory. Do we have any commands to skip the compilation and how to pass the path of artifactory to maven.